# Update self-referrencing table with MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table in MySQL for which certain rows can potentially be master of other rows in the same table.

The (simplified) structure of such table (let's say its name is `table1`) is:

| Id | IsMaster | Table1Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

In the above row Id:1 masters rows Id:2 and Id:3. I'm trying, given an Id, to `UPDATE` the `IsMaster` column. I'm aware you cannot `UPDATE` the same table you use in a `FROM` clause so I have two possible solutions at the moment but not sure which one to go with in terms of performance, these are:

```sql
 UPDATE table1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1Id
    SET t1.IsMaster = t2.Id IS NOT NULL
    WHERE t1.Id = @someId;
```

and

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1 
    SET t1.IsMaster = EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 1 FROM table1 t2 
        WHERE t2.Table1Id = t1.Id
        LIMIT 1
    ) as temp)
    WHERE t1.Id = @someId;
```

I'm putting my bet on the first `UPDATE` statement as the second one involves a temporary table but the first one would compute the whole join, right?

I'd like to know/hear your opinion/explanation on the above use case —and if there's another way?

Comment: So when you run these 2 queries, which one performs better?

Comment: @NickW Know of any benchmark tool/tutorial for MySQL?

Comment: Choosing the one that suits your use case best and performs well with your dataset is advisable

Comment: Why do you need a benchmark tool/tutorial (the recommendation of which would be off topic for this forum)? You can just run the queries and see how long they take to run

Answer (score -1):

By trying/testing with `SELECT` you can show why second is a better choice :

```
SELECT t2.Id IS NOT NULL AS NewIsMaster, t1.*
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1Id
WHERE t1.Id = 1;
```

VS

```
SELECT (EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 t2 
   WHERE t2.Table1Id = t1.Id
)) AS NewIsMaster, t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.Id = 1;
```